# Getting error wihle settng enviroment for ReactJS in my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, user-interface, reactjs-native

I am trying to set environment for ReactJS in my Ubuntu 18.04 and I followed this [link](https://codeburst.io/installing-reactjs-and-creating-your-first-application-d437706498ed) instructions. After installation used command 'start npm' (as instructed in the  link) in terminal to start but getting this error(see the img). After this I updated node.js and npm even after this I'm getting the same error. I'm beginner in UI Development.

[error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtxv.png)

Comment: Seems like you are trying this from root folder, you have to cd into the folder

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to cd into the project folder created and then run the command npm start. if the error prevails then check the package.json file for start command

```
"scripts": {
    "start": ""
  }
```